# Show also fixed price for bundle product when special price is set

Tags: magento-1, bundle, special-price

Currently when we set a special price for bundle product it shows the special price as configured price. We use bundles as package products so we hide all options and selections and bundles have only the default products attached to them.

We need to show also the fixed original price set for the bundle product. How could we show that too as a reference price for the special price?

Answer (score 0):

And here is the answer:

```
    <p class="normal-price-label"><?php echo $this->helper('bundle')->__('Normal price') ?>:</p>
    <span class="normal-price"><?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2) ?></span>
```